# How can I have more than six itemize environments in beamer?

Tags: beamer, itemize

When I have more than six `itemize` environments I get an error: `! LaTeX Error: Too deeply nested.` A runnable example below. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \itemize{\item{blah}} %1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \itemize{\item{blah}} %2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \itemize{\item{blah}} %3
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \itemize{\item{blah}} %4
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \itemize{\item{blah}} %5
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \itemize{\item{blah}} %6
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \itemize{\item{blah}} %7 -- Errors out. Delete this line and it compiles.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are not using an environment, as I read it. See ch. 12 in the beamer manual. \begin{itemize} \item whatever \end{itemize}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are **not** using an `itemize` environment, but only the `itemize` begin code without the corresponding `itemize` end code. Even using the start and end code of an environment instead of the environment should only be done if you really know what you are doing. But using the start code without the end code is mostly an error — in your case a nesting error, because the `\itemize` never end and therefore each new `\itemize` is counted as new nested list level.

Beginners should never misuse an environment as command or a command as environment. Environments  should be used with `\begin{environment} … \end{environment}`, as shown here:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}\item blah\end{itemize} %1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}\item blah\end{itemize} %2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}\item blah\end{itemize} %3
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}\item blah\end{itemize} %4
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}\item blah\end{itemize} %5
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}\item blah\end{itemize} %6
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}\item blah\end{itemize} %7
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico I have deliberately spoken of "itemize begin code" and "itemize end code" instead of mentioning `\itemize` and `\enditemize`. Since this is obviously a beginner's question, I want to avoid at all costs leading him down the wrong path `\itemize ...\enditemize` instead of `\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}`. Therefore, please do not include such commands in my answer. I consider them counterproductive.

Comment: I've rolled back my edit. Sorry for the bother.

Comment: "Since this is obviously a beginner's question" -- The OP has communicated in the meantime that they've been using TeX on and off for 30 years. Not exactly a beginner, I'd say...

Answer (score 2):

The following is meant as a companion piece to @cabobah's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/694927/5001), which explains that your code contains a syntax error: a multitude of `\itemize` instructions without corresponding `\enditemize` instructions. Moreover, there's no good reason for using `\itemize ... \enditemize` syntax instead of `\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}` syntax.

If, for some reason, you *insist* on using `\itemize ... \enditemize` syntax anyway, do note that neither `\itemize` nor `\item` take a brace-delimited argument. Thus

```
\itemize{\item{blah}}
```

is a prime illustration of the effects of code clutter. It could (should?) have been written more simply as

```
\itemize \item blah
```

Summing up, if you feel you must use `\itemize ... \enditemize` syntax, do write make a habit of writing

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \itemize \item blah \enditemize %1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \itemize \item blah \enditemize %2
\end{frame}

% ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you show a beginner how to use `\foo…\endfoo` you should also explain him, that this could be problematic, because of missing of several LaTeX features, e.g., check for correct nesting of environments, processing of some hooks … Currently this answer could be misinterpreted, that `\itemize …\enditemize` is the same like `\begin{itemize}…\end{itemize}`, which is definitely not the true.

Comment: @cabohah - That's why I pointed the reader to your answer and summarized the nature of the syntax error *before* I suggested a fix. :-) In my experience, some coders will insist on using poor syntax, no matter what. For such users, it may be better to provide a fix on an "official site" than to send them into the dark bowels of the Internet, where they may receive cure suggestions that are worse than the original malady...

Comment: Such coders often do not know, that their code has drawbacks, because they have been misleaded by others or misunderstandings. So, no, IMHO telling a beginner, that he also can use `\itemize …\enditemize` without telling him/her the drawbacks, is a bad idea.

Comment: @cabohah -- You wrote, "Such coders often do not know, that their code has drawbacks..."  Do we know for sure that the OP is a beginner? Couldn't the OP just as well be a semi-experienced user who has picked some questionable programming habits along the way? I suspect that such coders already know that their code has lots of drawbacks. But, for some reason, they wish to plow on and not adopt canonical syntax rules. Telling these coders politely that they ought to switch to official syntax will likely elicit scorn and, worse, may trigger some paranoid reactions and conspiracy theories...

Comment: The OP has been using TeX on and off for 30 years but never bothered to read the manual and clearly prefers to get results by picking random code snippets off the web - a questionable strategy that occasionally dead-ends. I appreciate the guidance.

Comment: @user443854 -- So definitely not a beginner, but not a gangster-coder either. :-)